# KeyListener - Why is the keyPressed method is delayed by one type?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener, documentlistener

What I want to do is the moment I pressed the keyboard, whatever is written on the textfield  will be shown in the System.out.printLn(). but for every type I make, it will only be shown if  I pressed another key.

for example.. I press 'A' ...then a blank space will be shown.
I press 'B' ...then 'A' will be shown.
I press 'C' ...then 'AB' will be shown.

what I want is if I press 'A' ...then 'A' will be shown...etc
is it possible? I also tried this on keyTyped() but the result is just the same..

here is my short code for this...

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class NewClass extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
NewClass(){
    this.setLayout(null);
    tf.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 30);

    add(tf);
    tf.addKeyListener(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass r = new NewClass();
    r.setVisible(true);
    r.setSize(300, 200);
    r.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(tf.getText());
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

}
```

Any suggestions? thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're trying to filter the text coming into the field, use a `DocumentFilter` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes. I will actually use this for a search box later. I will try that document filter. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `keyPressed` is being called *before* the TextBox is updated.

Instead of

```
tf.addKeyListener(this);
```

Try using this:

```
tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    printIt();
}
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    printIt();
}
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    printIt();
}

public void printIt() {
    System.out.println(tf.getText());
}
```

You'll need to import `javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent` and `javax.swing.event.DocumentListener`.